# SQL error when run command line upgrade Magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, command-line, setup-upgrade

When I run the following commmand:
`php bin/magento s:up;`
It throws the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'admin_magen34.mg7a_sm_products_filter' doesn't exist, query was: SHOW CREATE TABLE mg7a_sm_products_filter
>   Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: try to create the table `mg7a_sm_products_filter` manually

Comment: But how to know structure table mg7a_sm_products_filter  to create?

Comment: check which module has the error and from there, check its installschema and other related files

Comment: Now i find solution: phpmyadmin database - magento.. temp table not exists in database.. if can create than facing issue like table or view exists than go to /var/lib/mysql/ here find database folder name remove folder or remove temp.frm

Answer (score 0):

It means The `mg7a_sm_products_filter` table does not exist in `admin_magen34` DataBase so in that case two possible reasons.

1. Table not created.
2. Or the wrong DataBase configured in Magento.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thank for help. But the problem i don't structure this table in the database. How to to create table true field? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Now i find solution: phpmyadmin database - magento.. temp table not exists in database.. if can create than facing issue like table or view exists than go to /var/lib/mysql/ here find database folder name remove folder or remove temp.frm